# Explanation for the results of Topoisomerase I treatment of ERCs - Gel Electrophoresis

Tags: genetics, dna, gel-electrophoresis, yeast, restriction-enzymes

This part of a 1997 paper published in *The Cell* (David A. Sinclair & Leonard Guarente, 1997) discusses the presence of extrachromosomal rDNA circles (ERCs) in greater numbers in old mutant yeast cells when compared to young ones. All the lanes to the right of the "old untreated" lane are treatments carried out to the old yeast cells.

There are two scales on the figure, the left hand side has a scale for the length of linear DNA, while the right has one for circular DNA (I think?) which appears to move faster through the gel than linear DNA of an equivalent size.

Excluding the Kpn1 lanes and the young yeast cell lane, there are two clusters of bands around 19.3kb ccc and just above 40.4kb ccc. Would I be right in thinking that the writers are saying these clusters are due to the presence of concatenated ERCs (near the 40.4kb ccc marker) and non-concatenated ERCs (near the 19.3kb ccc marker)?

I don't understand the results of the topoisomerase I treatment, it doesn't look to change the gel much when compared to the old untreated yeast lane. The description states that the topoisomerase I treated rDNA migrates more slowly through the gel, though this doesn't seem evident from the figure. There is a "linear genomic [rDNA]" label on the LHS above the 40kb ccc on the RHS, though I am unsure what it is referring to. Presumably it is the size of fragments of the genomic rDNA after it has been treated with another restriction enzyme? But there is no prior restriction enzyme treatment mentioned. This is the part I am least sure about.

Excerpt from the paper relating to the figure in question is below, and the full paper is [linked here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0092-8674(00)80493-6).

> Several experiments were performed to investigate whether the circular rDNA molecules were oligomers of the 9.1 kb rDNA repeat. The
> rDNA molecules had a faster mobility relative to linear DNA size
> standards in the absence of ethidium bromide, a known property of
> circular DNA (Figure 3, between the 19.3 and 40.4 kb size markers).
> Digestion of old genomic DNA with KpnI (which cleaves once within the
> rDNA repeat unit) prior to electrophoresis reduced the ladder of bands
> to a single 9.1 kb species, demonstrating that the circular rDNA
> molecules consist of directly repeated multiples of the rDNA unit
> (Figure 3). Further, cleavage with BamHI had no effect on the banding
> pattern since rDNA is refractory to this enzyme. A partial KpnI digest
> reduced the abundance of the large circular species, while increasing
> the abundance of smaller ones. This implies that the large species are
> comprised of interlocked smaller circles (i.e., concatamers) that are
> released during digestion. Finally, treatment of the DNA with
> topoisomerase I, an enzyme known to relax supercoiled DNA, caused the
> mobility of these DNA species to migrate more slowly, coincident with
> the linear genomic rDNA (Figure 3). By quantitating the levels of
> total linear and extrachromosomal DNA from old wild-type cells (see
> Experimental Procedures), we estimate that the amount of ERC DNA in
> old cells can reach levels equal to the total linear yeast genome.

Thank you for your help.

[image: "Total DNA (15 μg) from either young or old sgs1 cells electrophoresed without ethidium bromide at 1 V/cm. Old cell DNA was treated with topoisomerase I, BamHI, or KpnI using standard conditions (Kim and Wang, 1995) and probed for rDNA. Sizes represent covalently closed circular markers (ccc). ABSC = 9.9 ± 4.4." - Figure caption from original paper]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this site exists to answer specific problems in biology that are likely to be of general interest. It is not a journal club to discuss the details of particular published papers.

Comment: I think it's okay to ask about particular papers, but some problems about this post are that the title is not a question or suggestive of a question, and the apparent question asked here is buried deep in the body of the post.

Comment: Thanks for your help! have changed the title and the length of the post. Just wanted to provide some context without people having to comb through the paper.